# Cross-domain problem when use VF component from managed package

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

The original problem is that one of our customers can't use our VF component in their org because of

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://c.xNN.visual.force.com/apex/yourpath' from origin 'https://xNN.salesforce.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have to mention that component has its own controller which is also suppled in the package.

I've tried to reproduce the problem in our orgs but no luck - everything works just fine. After a brief investigation I found that we have all VF component sources hosted on `force.com` domain, but customer has some data/sources hosted on 'salesforce.com' when another part is hosted on 'force.com'.

Can someone explain the difference between `salesforce.com` and `force.com`, and why this problem occurs only for one customer. Is there any setting I could miss that lead to this problem?

**UPD:**

Visualforce Page looks like

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <pkg_namespace:TheirComponent />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is your component designed to be used as an XHR? What structure of data does it return? (e.g JSON, String, XML, etc.)

Comment: @NickCook, it returns a html, and placed on the customers visualforce page. In fact visualforce page renderened on the layout within iframe. So i've tried to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but no luck